# Erlang - Return Number Of Elements

Tags: erlang

I found the solution to this problem, but it does not work properly.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26112622/9814501)

What is wrong? 
I always get the result 0.

```
num([]) -> 0;
num(NUMS) ->
        num(NUMS, 0).

num([H|L], Count) when H < 1 ->  %% use of guard
        num(L, Count+1);
num([_|L], Count) ->
        num(L, Count);
num([], Count) ->
        Count.
```

This is an example of use [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWZjs.jpg)

//Edit
I found where is problem. This is correct code.

```
num([]) -> 0;
num(NUMS) ->
        num(NUMS, 0).

num([H|L], Count) when H < 1 ->  %% use of guard
        num(L, Count+1);
num([_|L], Count) ->
        num(L, Count+1);
num([], Count) ->
        Count.
```

Comment: Why rebuild something that is currently in the core libs of Erlang `length([1,2,3,4])`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need first pattern in num/2 function:

```
num([_|L], Count) ->
        num(L, Count+1);
num([], Count) ->
        Count.
```

will be enough.